# Swiftmailer pdf attachment from snappy bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sendgrid, swiftmailer

I have an function `downloadPdf($id, \Knp\Snappy\Pdf $snappy, Request $request)`.

This function downloads a pdf with information from objects everything works fine.

This is the function:

```
public function downloadPdf($id, \Knp\Snappy\Pdf $snappy, Request $request): Response
{
    //search id
    $workOrder = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(WorkOrders::class)->find($id);

    //data to pdf template
    $html = $this->renderView('pdf/pdf.html.twig', array(
        'workOrder' => $workOrder,
    ));


    //name file
    $filename = $workOrder->getId();

    //download pdf
    return new PdfResponse(
        $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        $filename.'.pdf'
    );
}
```

And then I have an swift mailer function:

```
//check if signed and if check is true
        if ($data_uri) {
            //send workOrder to company
            if ($check == true) {
                $transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.sendgrid.net', 587))
                    ->setUsername('sendgridUSERNAME')
                    ->setPassword('sendgridPASSWORD')
                    ;

                $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

                $message = (new \Swift_Message('Werkbon '.$workOrder->getTitel()))
                    ->setFrom(['xxx' => 'xxx'])
                    ->setTo('xxx')
                    ->setBody('xxx')
                    ->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($this->downloadPdf()))
                    ;

                $result = $mailer->send($message);
            }
```

The email works fine but I want to attach the pdf from the other function to this email in the code above you can see what I tried but I think I got it totally wrong.
I have no idea where to start.

Can someone give me a little push in the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here is how it works for me,

```
$invoicepdf = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html);



/* And instead of returning pdf, send it with mailer: */

$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('YOUR_TITLE')
    ->setFrom('foo@from.net')
    ->setTo('foo@to.net')
    ->attach(\Swift_Attachment::newInstance($invoicepdf, 'your_file_name','application/pdf'))
    ->setBody("yyy");
$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I fixed it by saving the pdf before sending it. But what do you mean with `newInstance`?